# c# WinForm Inherited child (Form) cannot access parent collection property when parent has item populated

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

I have a BaseForm with a collection or a list, containing some typed objects which I want to share with child form. The idea is, I want my child form to be able to add/remove those objects as well. Those objects contain some definition of certain icons/buttons which I want to do visual inheritance.

So I have the following Base Form

```
[DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
public List<TItem> TItems
{
    get { return this._TItems; }
}

public FormBase()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    //TItems.Add(new TItem());
}
```

and a simple object

```
public class TItem
{
    public string T1 { get; set; }
}
```

Inheriting this base form I can freely modify the collection in designer for the child. But once I comment out that part which add an item from the parent form, the collection property in designer (for the child form) gray-out saying Read-Only.

I have tried different type of list, auto-property, changing DesignerSerializationVisibility.visible, initializing the list from child constructor... I just couldn't achieve what I want.

Can anyone point me to the right direction?

Comment: Try changing it to `BindingList<T>`.

Comment: I tried BindingList, List, ObservableCollection, IBindingList... all same result which the collection property was disabled on child.

Comment: I think the problem is that it doesn't know what type of instance to create.  I had thought that `BindingList`'s `ITypedList` would have fixed that.

Comment: I had the same thought as well. But even if I change to the list to be a List<string> the same thing happens. I then assume it is due to the ownership of the list.

Comment: Not necessarily.  That code was written before generics existed; it may not have been updated to know about generics.

Comment: Not 100% sure, but I don't think the designer can handle that situation since the parent form has a collection of items already. The child form can't figure out which items belong to "it".  WinForm inheritance was never a joy.

Comment: That's indeed the problem.  He's expecting the collection editor to know the difference between the items that are already in the list and the ones that are added at design time.  It doesn't have that feature.  Nor is it very simple to implement, a custom UITypeEditor that somehow knows the initial state of the list would be required.  You wouldn't do it that way anyway, you'd just have the designer initialize the list instead of the program.  Like the way TabControl works.

Comment: Thanks for all comments and explanations. With a work around I am able to achieve what I want by having another property to control whether to inherit the standards controls.